# React how to check overflow text before mounted?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

same with the title, I want to ask in React how to check overflow text before mounted?

I made an example like this

```js
const OverflowText = (props) => {
   const [isOverflow, setIsOverflow] = React.useState(false);
   const divRef = React.useRef(null);

 useEffect(() => {
   if (divRef.current) {
      const { scrollHeight, clientHeight, scrollWidth, clientWidth } = divRef.current;
      if (scrollHeight > clientHeight || scrollWidth > clientWidth) {
        setIsOverflow(true);
      } else {
        setIsOverflow(false);
      }
    }
 
 }, [])
 
 const core = <div className={'core'} ref={divRef}>{props.content}</div>
 return isOverflow ? (<div className={'wrapper'}>{core}</div>) : (core)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

So you can see in this example, i will check if the text content is overflow by checking `scrollHeight`, if it is overflow, i will trigger rerender and wrapped it with a `div` with className **wrapper**.

Now the problem is with this code, the component will need to render **twice**, which involve repaint and reflow of the page. Imagine if we got 100 components in a page, this would harm the performance of the page. Therefore, my question is is there anyway I can check if the text is overflow **on created** (before it even paint) so that it will automatically wrapped with wrapper `div` in the first time.

Thanks